# Delayed_job, sending mail from within a delayed method

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, delayed-job

I have a delayed method **async_checkout_assist** that runs as expected, gets added to the table and executes without any problem and gets removed from table after execute, but inside that delayed method I would like to send a mail if condition_is_true but when I add the mailer line it does not send the mail :\

---

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  async = ApplicationController.new #create new instance
  async.async_checkout_assist #call method

  def async_checkout_assist
    Mailer.delay.mailer_checkout_assist(@contact_name, @contact_email, @contact_tel)
  end

  end
  handle_asynchronously :async_checkout_assist, :run_at => Proc.new { 10.seconds.from_now }

end
```

---

**Update:**

delayed method (async_checkout_assist) gets added and run by worker

```
SQL (14.1ms)  INSERT INTO `delayed_jobs` (`attempts`, `created_at`, `failed_at`, `handler`, `last_error`, `locked_at`, `locked_by`, `priority`, `queue`, `run_at`, `updated_at`) VALUES (0, '2012-05-11 10:14:27', NULL, '--- !ruby/object:Delayed::PerformableMethod\nobject: !ruby/object:ApplicationController\n _routes: !!null \n _action_has_layout: true\n _headers:\n Content-Type: text/html\n _status: 200\n _request: !!null \n _response: !!null \nmethod_name: :async_checkout_assist_without_delay\nargs: []\n', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, '2012-05-11 10:14:37', '2012-05-11 10:14:27')
   (17.2ms)  COMMIT
```

```
Marais-Mac-mini:cybercellar.com_heroku davidmuller$ rake jobs:work
[Worker(host:Marais-Mac-mini.local pid:886)] Starting job worker
[Worker(host:Marais-Mac-mini.local pid:886)] ApplicationController#async_checkout_assist_without_delay completed after 9.5160
[Worker(host:Marais-Mac-mini.local pid:886)] Class#mailer_checkout_assist completed after 7.3627
[Worker(host:Marais-Mac-mini.local pid:886)] 2 jobs processed at 0.0923 j/s, 0 failed ...
```

**It now works with both**

```
Mailer.delay.mailer_checkout_assist(@contact_name, @contact_email, @contact_tel)
Mailer.mailer_checkout_assist(@contact_name, @contact_email, @contact_tel).deliver
```

Comment: 1. Is task being created in the delayed_job table? 2. Are you sure you have started delayed job worker process to handle the jobs?

Comment: yes I have restarted the worker, then the worker adds the async_checkout_assist method to table and runs it successfully, but when the method runs it does not send the mail

Comment: it seems to works now :|

Comment: no idea, I restarted the app and the worker again, seems to have did the trick